# Setting an array within a struct

Tags: java, renderscript

I'm attempting to set an array that is within a custom structure in Renderscript from Java.

Here is my struct:

```
typedef struct WorldState {
 float time;
 int galaxyRadius;
 float angle;
 int audioData[1024];
} WorldState_t;
```

Here is how I am attempting to set the array "audioData"

```
mScript.get_worldState().set_audioData(0, mAudioData, true);
```

This is the exception that is being thrown:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(8373): android.renderscript.RSIllegalArgumentException: Field packer sizelength 4096 does not match component size 4.
```

I only create a ScriptField_WorldState with size 1. From my understanding in the set_audioData method call, the first parameter needs to be 0 as there is only 1 WorldState element. I pass mAudioData which has a size of 1024.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that the reflected Java layer currently supports direct array manipulation in this fashion.  Since all memory allocations are managed by the Java side of Renderscript, I suggest changing

```
 int audioData[1024];
```

to

```
 rs_allocation audioData;
```

or

```
 int32_t *audioData;
```

and working with `audioData` in the same way that you work with other *allocations*.  More details on how this is done can be found here:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html#pointer
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html#allocating-mem
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/renderscript/Allocation.html

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! Unfortunately you cannot have a pointer within a struct so that only leaves rs_allocation. I'm currently trying to implement a solution but am having trouble figuring out how to access the elements within the allocation.